# jQuery loop to create a button

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have a jQuery function which onclick opens a dialog box. This allows a user to reply to a question.

The problem I am having is if there is more than one question the functionality only works on the first button created.

#### PHP CODE

```
$C = count($array2);
    for($i=0; $i < $C; $i++)
    {
        echo "<button id='reply'>Reply</button";
    }
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( name ),

    $( "#form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 700,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#reply" ).click(function() {
        $( "#form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

What I want is on the click on any of these buttons that the dialog box will open allowing the user to reply to a comment.

Thanks in advance.

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Reply button, you should use Class instead of Id. Please try these code:

.....

```
for($i=0; $i < $C; $i++)
{                                   
     echo "<button class='reply'>Reply</button";
}
```

.....

```
$( ".reply" ).click(function() {
      $( "#form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, IDs are meant to be unique. Consider using `reply` as a class instead:

```
echo "<button class='reply'>Reply</button>";
```

Now your code should work with:

```
$(".reply").click(function() {
    $( "#form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Secondly, you might want to consider delegating to the parent to avoid adding unnecessary event handlers. For example, if all of these reply buttons were contained in an element `#container`, you could use:

```
$('#container').on("click",".reply",function(){
    $( "#form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```